# Probability : Constructing a tree of probability question

Tags: probability

In a game, each trial consists of two possible outcomes, success or failure. Two trials $H$ and $K$ are carried out. The probability of success for trial $H$ is $x$, and the probability of success for trial $K$ is $2/5$ if trial $H$ is a success, and $x/2$ if trial $H$ is a failure. Given that the probability of trials $H$ and $K$ ending with one success is $1/5$, determine the value of $x$.

I approached this question by multiplying $(1-x)(x/2) = 1/5$, to which I didn't obtain answer at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Does "trials $H$ and $K$ ending with one success" mean "trials $H$ and $K$ ending with **exactly** one success"?

Comment: It must be exactly one success. Having at least one success is giving a probability either greater than 1 or less than zero, which is not possible. Therefore, the statement must mention exactly one success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to obtain exactly one success: Success on $H$ and failure on $K$, or failure on $H$ and success on $K$. The probability of the first option is $(x)(3/5)$, and the probability of the second option is $(1-x)(x/2)$. The sum of those two probabilities should be $1/5$.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, sir. I overlooked. After receiving your comment I instantly corrected my equation and I got the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

So $K$ is done after $H$,so we condition on the result of $H$

To get 1 success: $$P(H \land \lnot K) + P(\lnot H \land K) = P(\lnot K|H)P(H) + P(K| \lnot H)P(\lnot H) = \frac{3}{5} x + \frac{x}{2}(1-x)$$

and this should equal $\frac{1}{5}$